SharePoint mapped network drives lose connectivity (WebDAV/SMB Share)
We have mapped some SharePoint sites as network drive in Windows. If we open Windows Explorer and type site URL then it changes to path as below which we are able to map.
URL
https://localsharepoint.com/sites/oursite
Path
oursite (\\localsharepoint.com\@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites)
Problem is it keeps losing connectivity every now and then. When that happens, it shows red cross on drive and you cannot open it. Even if we open the site in browser to refresh the session, it doesn't work. The only way to make it work is to type URL again in Windows Explorer and then all mapped drives starts working.
My questions are:

Is this called SMB share or WebDAV?

Why does the session keep disconnecting and how to fix it?


